# How to manage Multilanguage website in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am building a website and in future it may have multilingual features. I just want to know about any database (e.g DataTypes ets.) or coding specifications that I should consider for this from the start so that multi language feature can be included at a later stage easily. Thanks

Comment: try this one [Multilingual Website In MVC 4 C#](http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2013/03/multi-language-website-in-mvc-4-c.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For database column types I'd keep all the text nVarchar if you're going to be storing text there.

You could also checkout .net resource files: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5447/NET-Localization-using-Resource-file

If you know for sure you're going to translate the site in the future, it wouldn't hurt to put everything in an English resource file now.

Answer (score 2):

You may create a [Satellite Assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/global_developer/archive/2011/07/22/introduction-to-satellite-assemblies.aspx) per culture, and then you can use that via resources to create a Multilingual website. You may look at the following articles:

[CodeProject - Creating multilingual websites](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7998/Creating-multilingual-websites-Part-1) 
[Multi-lingual web applications using ASP.Net 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2010/11/23/multi-lingual-web-applications-using-asp-net-4.aspx)